# C segfault 11 and possibly other errors with file i/o

Tags: c, macos, file-io, segmentation-fault

I wanted to write a simple programming language but I can't get past all these errors! Also to note, I am on Mac OS X, and the code below is all the code I have. I would be so excited if I could get this to work, and I am okay if I need to edit my language's syntax a bit. I think it is the path.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define buffersize 8192

int main(void) {
    char buff[buffersize];
    char filename[256];
    scanf("%s", filename);
    char rawfname[256];
    strcpy(rawfname, filename);
    int i;
    for(i=0; filename[i]!='.'; i++);
    while(rawfname[i]!='\0') {
        rawfname[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    char fileloc[256] = "Macintosh HD/Users/user/c/";

    char cfilename[256];
    strcpy(cfilename, rawfname);
    strcat(cfilename, ".c");

    char cfileloc[256];
    strcpy(cfileloc, fileloc);
    strcat(cfileloc, rawfname);
    strcat(cfileloc, ".c");

    strcat(fileloc, filename);

    FILE *fp = fopen(fileloc, "r");

    if(fp != NULL) {
        printf("Starting to compile...\n");
        printf("Creating .c file...\n");
        FILE *cfp;
        cfp = fopen(cfilename, "w");
        printf("Starting to create .c file..\n");
        fputs("#include <stdio.h>\nint main(void) {\n", cfp);
        printf("Started .c code...\n");

        int line = 1;
        printf("About to port to .c file...\n");
        while(fgets(buff, buffersize, fp) != NULL) {
            printf("Reading line %d", line);
            if(strcmp(buff, "print:")) {
                printf("Found print statment...\n");
                fgets(buff, buffersize, fp);

                line++;
                printf("Reading line %d\n", line);

                while(!strcmp(buff, "endprint")) {
                    char print[256] = " printf(";
                    strcat(print, (char*)22);
                    fputs(buff, cfp);
                    strcat(print, (char*)22);
                    strcat(print, ");\n");
                    fputs(print, cfp);
                    fgets(buff, buffersize, fp);
                }
            }
            line++;
        }
        fputs(" return 0;\n}", cfp);
        printf("Porting to .c complete...\n");

        printf("About to compile..\n");
        char compile[256];
        strcpy(compile, "gcc ");
        printf("Compile command started...\n");
        strcat(compile, cfilename);
        printf(".c file name added to compile command...\n");
        strcat(compile, " -o ");
        printf("' -o ' added to compile command...\n");
        strcat(compile, rawfname);
        printf("Executable file name added to compile command...\n");
        system(compile);
        printf("%s command executed...\n", compile);

        printf("\nFile read and compile complete...\n");
    } else {
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Here is the output of my program:

```
test.txt
Starting to compile...
Creating .c file...
Starting to create .c file..
Started .c code...
About to port to .c file...
Reading line 1
Found print statment...
Reading line 2
Found print statment...
Segmentation fault: 11
logout
```

test.txt:

```
print:
It works!
endprint
```

And test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fp` is a null pointer (because `if(!fp) {`). Also `strcat(print, (char*)22);` looks just wrong.

Comment: How about using a debugger, instead of pasting code here for others to debug it for you?

Comment: Also, you have several calls (`fgets`, `fopen` at least) where you don't check for errors.

Comment: Also, at least one of your debug prints is without newline at the end, which causes it to be buffered, and if you get segfault it may never get actually printed, which may lead to misleading output.

Comment: Is `"Macintosh HD/Users/user/c/"` a valid path under OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!fp)
```

should be

```
if(fp != NULL)
```

They both are not same.

Comment: This helped but It now it isn't opening the text file. I think it is the path.

Comment: @TucowUncow Yes please check the file path and the filename

Comment: I did and I am now getting segfault 11.